# fraction of coprime integers

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ and $q$ are coprime positives integers , then

$$(p / q)\cdot n \notin \mathbb Z, $$ for every $n = 1, 2, ..., q-1$.

With $n = 1$ this is trivial since there is no common divisor but why is it true for:

$(p / q)*2$ or $(p / q)*3$ as long as $n \le q-1$?

Many thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose otherwise.  Then we can right $pn=qm$  Then use $\gcd(p,q)=1$ to deduce that $q\,|\,n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there exist an integer $n\in\{1,2,...q-1\}$ and $m\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $\frac pq\times n=m$.

Multiply both sides by $q$ and we get $pn=qm$. Thus $q\ |\ pn$.

As $\gcd(p,q)=1$, thus $q$ must divides $n$.

Because $n\in\{1,2,...,q-1\}$, no such integer $n$ exist which leads to a contradiction.

There for $\frac pq \times n$ is not an integer

Comment: Many thanks that was really helpful! The hint from lulu was good but I was still struggling. Cheers, CR!

Comment: Just re-wording in a way that clicks and sticks :) If such an integer exists, say $m$ then we have 
$(p/q)*n=m$ which is equivalent to $p/q=m/n$ but since $p$ and $q$ are co-primes their fraction is irreducible. Since $n \lt q$ we have reduced the fraction $p/q$ which leads to a contradiction.